# Copied files from LINUX machine to OSX machine over external USB drive disappear

Tags: 14.04, mount, usb-drive, macosx, nfs

So here is my setup:

I have a LINUX machine, running Ubuntu 14.4 LTS. I have a Mac laptop, running OSX El Capitan, 10.11.1. Lastly, I have an external USB (4TB) drive. I formatted the drive to be compatible with Mac OSX. I am able to copy stuff to and from the usb drive just fine.

When I plug the USB driver into my LINUX machine, I am able to access it just fine. Then, I run the following command:

```
cp -r /me/stuff* /media/externalUsb
```

This then goes ahead and copies all stuff* files to my USB drive, and I can see this happening on the terminal.

I then take my USB drive out, and plug it into the Mac. At this point, I only see a very few select files of all the stuff* that was supposed to be copied over! I tried this twice already and got the same result.

What is the reason for this, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you remove the USB drive?  Do you sync from a terminal first? Do you use the eject on the Nautilus filemanager? Do you wait for the light to stop blinking on the drive?

Comment: @ubfan1 I just disconnect it physically. I tried to un-mount is, but the error I get is "Drive: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))"

Answer (score 1):

Discs should not be unplugged if they are in use (busy).  The copied files may still be in a buffer, not yet on the disc when the cp looks like it is done.  If you have a terminal with a current directory on the disk, that will keep it busy also, and maybe slow down a buffer flush to the device.  Having the filemanager show a directory on the disk will also keep it busy, so click on something else, like "Home" before you click on the "eject" button for the device.  At a terminal, typing "sync" will flush buffers, but the best way to tell is when the disk light stays off after the sync.  The more files, or the bigger they are, the longer the buffer flush will take.  The actual write to disk may be much slower than you think, a few mega bytes per second -- it may take awhile to write your files out completely.